# "Not downloading file in useable form" error when trying to make a Live USB stick on a Mac

Tags: live-usb, mac

I have downloaded ubuntu onto my Mac but when I click on the file I get message that The Following Disk images couldn't be opened..   Image  ubuntu-14.04  reason no mountable file systems. What do I need to do. I am trying to produce a USB version to use on a Dell laptop

Comment: The .iso file is in a format which can be used on `Disk Utility` app, which is on your Mac in the /Applications/utilities folder and be written to a e.g. USB stick there.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx